# Trying to configure Wifi on Linux with Java

Tags: linux, wifi, java, wpa-supplicant

Edit: In rethinking the problem, one questions stands out: Why can I simply connect to Wifi when going through the GUI, but I require root privileges if I want to connect through the command line?

I'm trying to modify a Linux Wifi connection programmatically through Java. I wrote my program to modify the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file with the relevant information, and then I issue an:

```
wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure
```

At first, things didn't work because the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file is owned by root, and I got a permissions error. I `chown`'d the file to be owned by me and reran things. Things worked perfectly.

But then I used the GUI to disconnect from the AP that I had connected to. When I looked at the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file the ownership had reverted back to root. This means that if I run my program again it won't work because of the permissions problem since I don't want to run MY program as root.

What's going on here? Why did the ownership of that file change? And how can I reliably modify the Wifi configuration from Java?

Comment: In general, system configuration files are owned by root.  Tools will likely expect this and correct it when they notice that it's wrong -- that's likely what you're seeing.  Why do you need to write this file with a Java program?

Comment: @AndyDalton  I'm building a very simplified interface for unsophisticated users that will sit on top of Linux. Everything in the computer will be accessed through a browser interacting with a web app that's running on the box. Configuring WiFi the "normal way" is much too complex (what's a Pre-Shared Key?????) so there's a simple interface that I've built. At some point my code needs to actually configure the Wifi and I understand that wpa_supplicant is the accepted way. I don't want to run my code as root, so here we are. Is there a better way?

Comment: If you're building a simplified interface that enables users to configure the system, then parts of it will need root access (or at least something with root privileges to update the system configuration).  Maybe someone else here will have a better idea, but I cannot think of one.

Comment: @AndyDalton Well I don't really want people to "configure" their system, I just want them to be able to easily connect to Wifi. Going through the GUI interface to connect doesn't seem to require root privileges (or does it???) , so why can't I find a way to do it through a command line interface without needing root?

Comment: You can connect to WiFi using the GUI because the GUI communicates with a daemon (e.g. Network Manager) which *does* run as root and does the actual connection, and that daemon's configuration files are owned by root.